# Passing dynamic parameter to urlpatterns or DefaultRouter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have several categories that I want to create distinct views for in rest_framework. But all the categories pull from the same model.

It strikes me that these categories could be passed to `urlpatterns` as a keyword (or accessed through the `DefaultRouter`). Then you can use the keyword to filter the model as required.

Here's my view:

```
class CategoryRankedViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CategoriesSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Categories.objects.all().order_by(self.kwargs['category'])
```

One way I was able to make this work was:

```
urlpatterns = [path('<' + category + '>/', CategoryRankedViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name=category) for category in CATEGORIES]
```

But it's not perfect because the key for the parameter is set to the value of first item in `CATEGORIES`, rather than a more generic term like `category`.

I was considering `DefaultRouter` but it is not obvious if parameters can be passed to `DefaultRouter`.

I was also looking for ways that the literal url could be accessed and accessing the category that way. Does not appear this is possible in a ViewSet in DRF.

Also, `base_name` for `DefaultRouter` could be set dynamically, but I could not find how `base_name` can be accessed from a ViewSet.

Has anyone ever tried this and is there a more effective method?

***UPDATE***
As it turns out, `path()` has `kwargs` attribute that passes the keywords without them being included as url parameters. So don't pass the category as a url parameter. Just use the category variable in the url path and pass category as a keyword.

```
urlpatterns = [path(category + '/', CategoryRankedViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), kwargs={'category': category}, name=category) for category in CATEGORIES]
```

Is there any way to replicate this using `DefaultRouter`???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A viewset may mark extra **actions** for routing by decorating a method with the **@action** decorator.
You can use action decorator for your problem

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action

class CategoryRankedViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CategoriesSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Categories.objects.all().order_by(self.kwargs['category'])

    @action(methods=['get'],detail=False,url_path=r'list/(?P<category>[\w-]+)',url_name='categorylist')
    def get_category(self,request,category=None):
        return Categories.objects.all().order_by(category)
```

so, now you can provide any category in url and access it using category variable.
your url will be like **rooturl/list/{categoryhere}**.This url will call **get_category** method.
Remember the **url_path** uses only regular expression, so you cannot use slug there.
you can see the code of action decorator in this [link](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/decorators.py) and you can see the example of @action decorator in [djagorest](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/?q=%40action).
I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: does `get_category` override `get_queryset`?

Comment: No it is not overriding get_queryset,  get_category is a complete new method.

Comment: in @action decorator you have to pass url_path to access get_category using that path.